# Single word to describe some tasks performed sequentially

Tags: single-word-requests, technical, medical

I'm searching for a single word to describe a *session* made of independent tasks performed sequentially.

For example when you go to a medical center (this is the context where it has to be used then technical terms are preferred) and they perform many exams to achieve a diagnosis:

> *"In order to diagnose your problem in this* [word here] *we need to perform an Exercise ECG and an angiography"*.

I thought about *session* but I'm not sure it's right one and I'd prefer something else because it's already used on the same context with another meaning. Also *examination* may be an option but I'm not sure about its usage in this context.

**EDIT**: assume performed tasks are generically called *procedure* or *test*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to be a nurse and thought this might help.

You see a doctor for a consultation.  No diagnosis would take place during the consultation.  In order to achieve a diagnosis, a series of routine medical tests must be carried out.  The results should indicate if there is anything wrong.

Comment: Thank you, did you use any particular word referring to these tests (all together)? "Consultation" is the whole thing (including the act to _ask_ doctor), tests are the _things_ that will be performed, what's the word to name these "things" as an ensemble or it is "consultation"?

Comment: Diagnostic procedures would have been the one that I was most familiar with.  Does this help?

Comment: Yes, absolutely! I'm not native speaker so I'm not sure I can explain myself, word I'm looking for (if it exists) is for the whole set of (diagnostic) procedures you perform within a consultation. Is it "consultation" (then also including other things such as diagnosis and eventually _talking_ with doctor to gather information) or there is a more specific term?

Comment: I think you might be talking about a medical work-up where a panel of chemical tests such as blood and urine tests have become routine.  Occasionally, you can have a general medical check-up where you have routine tests done within the consultation.  I think this might suit your description better .  I can appreciate how hard it is to learn English.  i am a native speaker and still have some problems :)

Answer (score 2):

One could certainly call that diagnostic session an *examination* or *exam*.

**In order to diagnose your problem during this exam, we need to perform...**

*Exam* is what the doctor or nurse would call it when speaking to the patient.

The doctors must perform many *tests*, such as an EEG.

Answer (score 1):

"Process" would be a much better fit in general (if it's not specifically targeted to the medical example that you're presenting).